# Redirect to another site through input type button

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have two sites configured on my localhost:

i.e. : `http://localhost/site1/create.tpl` and `http://localhost/site2/create.php`

I want to redirect from site1 create page to site2/create via input type button.

How can I do this. I am using this

```
<input type="button" name="doCreate"  value="{$labels.btn_create}" onclick='window.location="http://localhost/site2/create.php"'/>
```

but not working. I am having the smarty and .tpl file and I am totally new in smarty.

please help

Comment: in html there is a tag called <a> which can handle your task

Comment: Your script is working fine for me, i just replaced the value attribute as test like below <input type="button" name="doCreate"  value="test" onclick='window.location="http://localhost/test/"'/>​

Comment: Check for any js errors in chrome developer tool or using firebug in FF

Comment: its working fine in smarty too, i tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have worked, but might try to add one attribute `href`:

```
<input type="button" name="doCreate"  value="{$labels.btn_create}" onclick='window.location.href="http://localhost/site2/create.php"'/>
```

PS: See [this](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html) small tutorial for more options.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong, I tested, and it works, it redirects me to the site: `http://localhost/site2/create.php`

Comment: Its `create.tpl` file and I want to redirect it from there. I edited my question

Comment: Load your site and look how the actual source looks like. If you create a test page you will see, that the line works.